# Deep-learning VM hourly cost?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am a student and I want to use Colab with a VM so I can have more GPU power. I live in the Netherlands so Colab Pro is not available.

However, when I want to config a VM the monthly cost are really expensive. We are talking about EUR 1,147.98/mo. Can I also pay by the hour? Since I don't need to use it that long!

Comment: You will most likely have another problem. Unless your account is **established**, which means you have been using it for a few months and paying on time, your quota to use GPUs will not be approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMs on GCP are [priced](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing) based on actual usage, with 1 minute minimums and thereafter charged *per second*. You just need to shut down the VM when it's not in use, and turn it back on when you need it again. [Discounting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts) is based on total usage as it adds up throughout the month, so if you end up using it enough to reach a discount it will be automatically applied.